# Bubble sort 2d array in alphabetical order only using iostream?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11

I'm trying to figure out how I can sort a list of words in alphabetical order. The code I have now will sort them correctly, only if each word is only 1 letter. Once I move to more letters, it fails. Can you help me fix this. Thanks

My input file is:

```
Emma
Liam
Dill
Bill
Kimm
Jacks
John
Hats
Julia
Jill
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void sort(char input[10][25], int size);

int main(){
    char input[10][25] = {"Emma", "Liam", "Dill", "Bill", "Kimm", "Jacks", "John", "Hats", "Julia", "Jill"};

    sort(input,10);

    cout << "Sorted:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << input[i];
    }

    return 0;
}


void sort(char input[10][25],int size){

    char temp;
    for(int k = 0;k < 10;k++){
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 24; j++){
                if(input[i][j] > input[i+1][j]){
                    temp = input[i][j];
                    input[i][j] = input[i+1][j];
                    input[i+1][j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend starting with helper functions. (1) A function to compare two strings, to see which comes before the other lexicographically. (2) A function to swap two strings position in the array, to help place them in the correct order.

Comment: `"John" "Hats"` missing a comma so this will cause a UB later when trying to read element `input[9]` which is not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code, is that when 1 word needs to be swapped with another, you do not swap the two words in the array. Instead you swap just the characters of the first word, which are larger than the characters of the second word. This creates a jumbled mess.

For example, when you try to Swap the following two rows

```
SALLY
MOMMA
```

Your end result is:

```
MALLA
SOMMY
```

Another problem include missing a comma between "John" and "Hats", resulting in only 9 entries in the array, one of them being "JohnHats".

Lastly, your bubble sort needs to use different indices in your loops to preserve the already sorted elements.

Using helper functions helps make this more clear. Here's an example solution close to what you originally wrote but with helper functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool smaller(char input[10][25], int a_index, int b_index) {
    char* a = input[a_index];
    char* b = input[b_index];
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != 0 && b[i] != 0; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << " " << b[i];
        if (a[i] > b[i]) {
            return false;
        } else if (a[i] < b[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void swap(char input[10][25], int a, int b) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        char temp = input[a][i];
        input[a][i] = input[b][i];
        input[b][i] = temp;
    }
}

void sort(char input[10][25], int size){
    char temp;
    for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++){
        for(int i = k + 1; i < 10; i++){
            if (smaller(input, i, k)) {
                swap(input, i, k);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char input[10][25] = {"Emma", "Liam", "Dill", "Bill", "Kimm", "Jacks", "John", "Hats", "Julia", "Jill"};

    sort(input,10);

    cout << "Sorted:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << input[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have a UB in your code:

```
string input[10] = {
        "Emma", "Liam", "Dill", "Bill", "Kimm",
        "Jacks", "John" "Hats", "Julia", "Jill"}; // a great problem here:
```

`"John" "Hats"`: missing a comma will cause a great disaster.

You can use class string easily instead of an array of constant strings so you need only to compare the first letter of each word in the array and swap if the condition is true:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void sort(string input[10]);


int main()
{

    string input[10] = {
        "Emma", "Liam", "Dill", "Bill", "Kimm",
        "Jacks", "John", "Hats", "Julia", "Jill"};

    sort(&input[0]);

    for(int i(0); i < 10; i++)
        cout << input[i] << ", ";

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}


void sort(string input[10])
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if(toupper(input[i][0]) > toupper(input[j][0])) // I used `toupper()` to not distinguish between small and capital letters
            {
                string temp = input[i];
                input[i] = input[j];
                input[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- If you want a full comparison which means compare the first letter of the two words and if they equal then compare the seconds and so on you need some extra work or use some facilities of some classes.

Answer (score 0):

To make the code more readable, let's define a swap method:

```
void Swap_Names(char a[25], char b[25])
{
  char c;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
  {
    c = a[i];
    a[i] = b[i];
    b[i] = c;
  }
}
```

A comparison function may make the code more readable:

```
bool Is_Less_Than(char a[25], char b[25])
{
  bool is_less = false;
  for (unsigned int 0 = 1; i < 25; ++i)
  {
    if (a[i] != b[i])
    {
       is_less = a[i] < b[i];
       break;
    }
  }
  return is_less;
}
```

A bubble sort works by swapping items, in your case, names.

```
void Bubble_Sort(char input[10][25], unsigned int size) // size can't be negative.
{
  bool swap_occurred = true;
  while (swap_occurred)
  {
    swap_occurred = false;
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < 9; ++index)
    {
      if (! Is_Less_Than(input[index], input[index + 1]))
      {
        Swap_Names(input[index], input[index + 1]);
        swap_occurred = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort is a poor sorting algorithm.

But it does have one advantage, which is that it can easily sort data you don't hold in memory, as long as you can hold a temporary.
One each pass load the first two data items. Then save the lower one back to the file, and keep hold of the higher. Continue loading in one by one and saving the lower. Finally save the higher.

You don't need random access to the data, though you do need to be able to pass through it at will.